# Let users create multiple playlists in Drupal website

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, flags, playlist

How can I let users create their own lists of a particular content type? I have used the "Flag" module but it allows only a single list. I want the user to be able to create multiple lists. I have tried "Flag lists" but cannot seem to get it working. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple flags like flag1 for playlist1, flag2 for playlist2 and so on. and use flag api's to display them with content.
To display all the flags you can create tpl files for your content-type and display all the flaging links with flag api URL: https://www.drupal.org/node/1748148 .
Later you can use views to display the individual playlist.